# PowerShell Get-PhysicalDisk MediaType returns no data on servers

Tags: ssd, powershell, windows-server-2012, wmi

I want to use `Get-PhysicalDisk | select MediaType` to find SSD drives.

Like the question said, fails on Server 2012 R2.

Also tried using VBScript WMI:

```
On Error Resume Next
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PhysicalMedia",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    MsgBox "MediaType: " & objItem.MediaType
Next
```

No joy.

Comment: Try `Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | Where-Object { $_.model -match "SSD" }`.

Comment: The code returns nothing at all on Server 2012 R2 - no error, either.

On Windows 10 1903 get this:
`Cannot run a document in the middle of a pipeline: C:\WINDOWS\system32\Get-WmiObject....CantActivateDocumentInPipeline`

Comment: What adapter is the drive attached to? A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+server+2012+Re+detect+SSD) shows related problems with raid(capable) controllers.